# Java-Scala interop issue involving BoxedUnit/void return types

Tags: java, scala, twitter, interop, twitter-util

I have the same problem as in [Java interoperability woes with Scala generics and boxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643045), but I don't think the solution there will work for me because it would require a modification to third-party code.

Specifically, *from Java* (say MyJavaClass) I'm trying to extend a Scala class (MyScalaClass) that itself extends [com.twitter.app.App](https://twitter.github.io/util/docs/index.html#com.twitter.app.App). App extends [com.twitter.util.CloseAwaitably](https://twitter.github.io/util/docs/index.html#com.twitter.util.CloseAwaitably), and this in turn extends [com.twitter.util.Awaitable](https://twitter.github.io/util/docs/index.html#com.twitter.util.Awaitable).

```
Awaitable            // trait where `result` is defined
 ^-CloseAwaitably    // trait with some impl of `result`
   ^-App             // trait with no mention of `result`
     ^-MyScalaClass  // abstract class with no mention of `result`
       ^-MyJavaClass // just trying to get this guy to compile
                     // and it expects an impl of `result`
```

All that to say that when I finally get to extending MyScalaClass by writing MyJavaClass, I get

> [ERROR] MyJavaClass.java:[11,8] MyJavaClass is not abstract and does
>   not override abstract method
>   result(com.twitter.util.Duration,com.twitter.util.Awaitable.CanAwait)
>   in com.twitter.util.Awaitable

I figured I just have to implement `result` for some reason, so I do, in MyJavaClass:

```
public void result(com.twitter.util.Duration d,
                   com.twitter.util.Awaitable.CanAwait c)
{}
```

Now I get

> [ERROR] return type void is not compatible with scala.runtime.BoxedUnit

Changing my method to

```
public BoxedUnit result(com.twitter.util.Duration d,
                        com.twitter.util.Awaitable.CanAwait c)
{return BoxedUnit.UNIT;}
```

results in

> [ERROR] return type scala.runtime.BoxedUnit is not compatible with void

What the heck... So then I start googling. The answer to [Java interoperability woes with Scala generics and boxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643045) seems to say that Scala generates Java-incompatible bytecode in my situation, and that I could hack around the problem if I had control of some of the Twitter classes (I *think* CloseAwaitably) to genericize  it with `[U <: Unit]` and `return ().asInstanceOf[U]` in the original method implementation to trick scalac into admitting the possibility of "some not-exactly-Unit type" (though I'm not totally clear on how this works).

I don't have control over the Twitter classes, only MyScalaClass and MyJavaClass. *I don't actually care about the* `result` *method* - I just want to be able to extend MyScalaClass from MyJavaClass, implementing some abstract methods I defined in MyScalaClass. For what it's worth, I'm using Scala 2.10.4, JDK 1.8, and (twitter) util-core_2.10 6.22.0, and in case this is relevant: I don't really know why it's requiring me to implement `result` in the first place. A Scala class inheriting from MyScalaClass doesn't have to implement that method, and builds just fine.

How can I get around this? Thanks for playing.

Comment: Can't you write a Scala wrapper class that forwards from some other method that you provide in your Java class?

Comment: Maybe, but my efforts in that direction so far have been unfruitful. Trying to override `result` from Scala always results in `error: method result overrides nothing.` I've tried every corruption of the signature I could think of. Also, it's not *necessary* to implement `result` from any Scala subclass for some reason, which makes me suspicious that something wonky is going on.

Comment: Doesn't this look like it should override the `result` in `CloseAwaitably` from a subclass? `override def result(timeout: Duration)(permit: CanAwait): Unit = {super.result(timeout)(permit);}` It apparently doesn't.

Comment: If I remove the `override` from the beginning of that and try to recompile, I get `name clash between defined and inherited member` and `...have same type after erasure` instead of `method result overrides nothing`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a similar trick to get Scala's part right, but javac still gets confused because it's looking for things that are "wrong" rather than those that are right.  (The JVM looks for what is right, so it runs fine.)

The gory details are as follows.

The Twitter hierarchy can be simplified as follows:

```
package test

trait A[+Z] { def z(): Z }
trait B extends A[Unit] { def z() = () }
trait C extends B {}
```

Now, when you write your class, you don't just extend C.  Instead, you

```
package test

abstract class D[U <: Unit] extends A[U] with C {
  override def z: U = (this: B).z.asInstanceOf[U]
}

abstract class E extends D[Unit] {}
```

where `E` takes the place of `MyScalaClass`.  (And `z` is `result`.)

Now, with the extends-unit trick, all the signatures that Java could possibly want are present:

```
$ javap test.B
public interface test.B extends test.A{
    public abstract void z();
}

$ javap test.D
public abstract class test.D extends java.lang.Object implements test.C{
    public scala.runtime.BoxedUnit z();
    public java.lang.Object z();
    public void z();
    public test.D();
}
```

`void z` is not abstract any more!  In fact, nothing is.

But javac *still* isn't happy.

```
package test;

public class J extends E {
  public J() {}
}

$ javac -cp /jvm/scala-library.jar:. J.java
J.java:3: test.J is not abstract and does not override
          abstract method z() in test.B
```

Um...javac, yes it does?

And if we make `J` abstract itself, it explains what the real problem is:

```
J.java:3: z() in test.D cannot implement z() in test.B; 
          attempting to use incompatible return type
found   : scala.runtime.BoxedUnit
required: void
```

That is, if two methods differ only by return type, and it's not the Java-sanctioned generic Object vs something-else, javac won't find the correct one.

This looks to me like a javac bug more than a scalac one.  Unfortunately, it leaves you unable to implement the classes in Java.

As a workaround, you can (awkwardly) use composition by linking two classes together.

Java:

```
package test;

public interface I {
  public void doThing();
}
```

Then Scala:

```
package test

trait A[+Z] { def z(): Z }
trait B extends A[Unit] { def z(): Unit = println("Ok") }
trait C extends B {}

class D extends C {
  private var myI: I
  def i = myI
  def bind(newI: I) { myI = newI }
  def doJavaThing = i.doThing
}
```

Then Java again:

```
package test;

public class J implements I {
  public static D d;
  public J(D myD) { d = myD; d.bind(this); }
  public void doThing() { System.out.println("Works!"); }
}
```

Which at leasts let you switch back and forth whenever you need to:

```
scala> new test.J(new test.D)
res0: test.J = test.J@18170f98

scala> res0.doThing
Works!

scala> res0.asScala.doJavaThing
Works!

scala> res0.asScala.asJava.doThing
Works!
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this? I get that in D, `method result overrides nothing`. I've tried using my actual MyScalaClass implementation, and with your stripped-down version (and names), and the error is the same.

Comment: trait D[Z1 <: Unit] extends Awaitable[Z1]  {
  override def result(timeout: Duration)(implicit permit: CanAwait): Z1 = {().asInstanceOf[Z1]}
}
abstract class E extends App with D[Unit] {}
public class J extends E {}
// This gives me `J is not abstract and does not override abstract method result(com.twitter.util.Duration,com.twitter.util.Awaitable.CanAwait) in com.twitter.util.CloseAwaitably`
Which is interesting, because CloseAwaitably is B in your scheme, extending A...

Comment: You can ignore my first comment because I just hadn't marked `permit` with `implicit`. Having done that, second comment referencing CloseAwaitably seems to be a clue of some sort. I seem to have successfully captured `result` from Awaitable, only to fail to capture the `result` in CloseAwaitably.

Comment: @danielpcox - Why are you overriding `result`?  It's not defined anywhere.  I don't override `z` in my example.

Comment: Isn't `result` defined in CloseAwaitably? If I remove `override` from the above, I get `[ERROR]   method result in trait CloseAwaitably of type (timeout: com.twitter.util.Duration)(implicit permit: com.twitter.util.Awaitable.CanAwait)Unit  and
[ERROR]   method result in trait D of type (timeout: com.twitter.util.Duration)(implicit permit: com.twitter.util.Awaitable.CanAwait)Unit
[ERROR] (Note: this can be resolved by declaring an override in class E.)`

Comment: @danielpcox - Ah, I had missed that.  Whew.  This is a mess.  Updated the answer (tl;dr--no solution, sorry).

Comment: Thanks Rex. I'm going to try your additions out soon and mark this as the answer. Who should I tell about these problems? How should I tell them? I think this should be regarded as a bug by *someone*. :)

Comment: @danielpcox - https://issues.scala-lang.org covers the Scala side.  http://bugreport.java.com/ is for Java.  Not sure if either has this issue already.