# How to provide Java callbacks (with 'void' return type), to Scala?

Tags: java, scala, language-interoperability

I've made a library in Scala that has a Java API.

I'd like to provide such a callback (Java):

```
private static void onB(Stats stats) {
   //... implementation does not matter
}
```

The Scala API has this as a class parameters or a method of an abstract class.

```
class LoggerJava(
  onBatch: Stats => Unit,
)
```

Problem is, I cannot provide a function `onB` as above, to the Scala API. This is needed:

```
new LoggerJava(
  (Stats stats) -> { onB(stats); return null; },
)
```

This is perhaps two different questions. I'm mostly interested to hear the patterns that people use for such cases. The aim being that the user of the library does not need to act different, because of the implementation language.

Scala 2.13
JVM 8+

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527166/java-scala-interop-issue-involving-boxedunit-void-return-types and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643045/java-interoperability-woes-with-scala-generics-and-boxing address this, but their use cases are way more complex than mine. Also, they are from pre-Scala 2.13

Comment: What is the error you get for `new LoggerJava(ClassName::onB)` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you provide an API specifically for Java, just use the Java functional interfaces of the JDK.

```
import java.util.function.Consumer

class LoggerJava(
  onBatch: Consumer[Stats],
)
```

If your Java API needs to interface with code that uses Scala functions, you can easily convert them.

```
import scala.jdk.FunctionConverters._

private val scalaApi = new LoggerScala(onBatch.asScala)
```

The alternative is that users of your Java API have to convert all their lambda's. E.g.

```
import scala.jdk.javaapi.FunctionConverters

new LoggerJava(FunctionConverters.asScalaFromConsumer(ClassName::onB))
```